# Randomly Sampling KWIC Examples in Quanteda

Tags: sample, quanteda

I'm trying to randomly sample KWIC examples from a rather large corpus.  For smaller corpora, I was able to view the KWIC output in its entirety using xtable and then create random numbers lists to identify and copy and paste the random examples. But for larger corpora, this doesn't work because the KWIC object has over 500,000 examples in it.

Is there any way to code this so I could limit the KWIC object to just a random sample of 30 or 40 of the hits rather than a list of all hits?  Many thanks for your help. I don't see any obvious approaches in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I should have worked a little harder on trying to find an answer to my own question.  The following code works for what I was hoping to do:

requirekwic <- kwic(cfrcorpus, pattern = "requir*", window = 50)

samplerequirekwic <- requirekwic[sample(nrow(requirekwic), 15),]

Comment: Yep, that's how to do it.